# Всё ли правильно в этом предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, грамотная-речь, грамматика

У другой же стены на короткой скамье отдельно сидела женщина лет тридцати пяти-сорока в очень не новой шубе, в сером головном платке, **с которого ворс начисто вытерся, и всюду обнажилась простая клетка вязки.** [Александр Солженицын. В круге первом, т.1, гл. 26-51 (1968) // «Новый Мир», 1990]

Интересуют два последних предложения: их вид и запятая между ними.

Comment: Полагаю, запятая отделяет присоединительное предложение.

Comment: @ Серж, вряд ли. Там же про ворс говорится, в принципе это связанные по смыслу предложения. Мне кажется, что они читаться должны без паузы и запятая не нужна. Там, вероятно,  пропущено  местоимение "на котором". Автор просто не хотел его повторять (как в недавно заданном на форуме вопросе).

Comment: Солженицын не был стилистом, и так сойдёт.

Comment: @Niemand  Ему, может быть, и сойдет, но вопрос задан о правильности предложения. Предложение некорректное? Тогда какие в нем ошибки, как их исправить?

Comment: @Sharon, вы правы. Можно рассматривать как однородные придаточные. Я тоже склонялся именно к этой версии. Но мне нигде не удалось найти варианта без запятой. Поэтому я написал о присоединительном характере.

Comment: Я добавлю не по теме, уж извините. Меня беспокоит, что нет запятой между "лет тридцати пяти-сорока в очень не новой шубе". Это же описание внешности, пусть с разных ракурсов.

Comment: Да, там тоже нестыковочка. Можно поставить запятую, но даже она это предложение не сделает лучше. Просто не знаю даже, как отредактировать, если только всё переделать.

Comment: Вместо  "и" можно поставить "от чего" - если "клетка вязки" к платку относится.

Comment: Да, как вариант. Ну тогда вот что у меня получилось: "У другой же стены на короткой скамье отдельно сидела женщина лет тридцати пяти-сорока, // в очень не новой шубе и  сером головном платке, ворс с которого начисто вытерся,// отчего всюду обнажилась простая клетка вязки".  И еще паузы пришлось поставить, чтобы правильно читать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне думается, что в указанной части предложения необходима правка "двух моментов".

**I.** В энциклопедическом словаре:
[вы́тереться](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/es/101747) , вы́терся, вы́тершись; св.
**2.** *Разг.* Износиться, стать потёртым. ***Воротник вытерся. Обивка вытерлась.***

В словаре Ушакова:
**стере́ться**, сотру́сь, сотрёшься, *прош.* стёрся, стёрлась; стёршись, *сов.* (к стираться).
1. Исчезнуть от трения или от воздействия каких-нибудь внешних причин.
Краска на скамейке стёрлась. Надпись на камне стёрлась от времени.
2. Уменьшиться в объёме, потерять выпуклости от трения при употреблении.
Чеканка на монете стёрлась.

Должно быть, как мне кажется, так: *платок **вытерся***, но *ворс **стёрся.***

*Однако при внимательном взгляде становилось очевидно, что пиджаку с пуговицами, обтянутыми вытершимся бархатом, по крайней мере лет сорок* (Ю. Поляков); *А на полулежит их ковёр, только целый, не разрезанный, краски его ярки и ворс не стёрся* (Н. Соротокина).

**II.** Вопрос о запятой перед **и** отпадет, если использовать общее относительное местоимение *которы*й в нужном падеже — *на котором.*

Получится, считаю, щадяще для текста и без изменения смысла:
*У другой же стены на короткой скамье отдельно сидела женщина лет тридцати пяти-сорока в очень не новой шубе, **в сером головном платке, на котором ворс начисто стерся и всюду обнажилась простая клетка вязки.***

Comment: Да, хороший вариант, мне нравится.  Даже если не вникать в тонкости различия двух глаголов, замена вполне корректная. А эта замена освобождает  от необходимости очень нежелательного повтора местоимения "который",  Спасибо. Я же говорю, что наши энтузиасты получше профессионалов будут, потому что любят русский  язык и внимательны к нему, в то время как специалисты (из Грамоты.ру, например) не находят времени ни для любви, ни для внимательности.

Comment: @Sharon Гугло-книги находят хорошие издания и без запятой, встречается также слитное написание "неновой". Подозреваю, проблема в том, что первые издания выходили "самизадтом" или в других странах и не прошли через работу хорошего корректора. А теперь множится хаос перепечаток с тех изданий.

Comment: В очень неновой шубе - такое написание возможно, учитывая наличие наречия степени, характерного для слитного письма.  А без запятой перед союзом И можно писать однородные придаточные, а в это случае нужно повторение слова "который" (с которого и на котором).